# Visual Studio 2015 - Where's the gulp task runner?

Tags: gulp, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I heard Mads Kristensen in his videos mention that Gulp and Grunt are both first class citizens. I thought I even heard mention of the Gulp task runner.

But when I create a gulpfile and right click there's no task runner.

Has anyone been able to get the "native" gulp task runner (if there is one) in Visual Studio 2015 Preview to appear?

Comment: you can look there for more information: http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/grunt-and-bower-in-visual-studio-2015#bower

Comment: Sorry but this does not answer the question at all. I have looked at that page before and it mentions nothing about the Gulp task runner.

Comment: After upgrading from win 7 to win 10 (and from git to tfvc the following day) I had to reinstall all of npm and gulp modules to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I solved the problem with several restarts of VS2015. Finally the task runner appeared for my gulpfile. I still have no idea why it did not appear from the start but it's a preview version so maybe something is not quite right yet.

Answer (score 46):

View > Other Windows > Task Runner Explorer and click refresh

[image]

or just `Ctrl + Alt + Bkspace`

Comment: The question wasn't where the task runner window is, the question is why it doesn't recognize gulp files. Mads should have been marked as answer - sounds like they know the tooling isn't quite there yet.

Comment: I've never installed Gulp globally, and it's now here for VS2015 RC

Comment: Your comment helped me because I couldn't find task runner window easily

Answer (score 4):

The Preview version of VS2015 requires Gulp to be installed globally and has a few other issues with auto-discovery of the gulpfile.js. These issues will all be addressed by the time VS2015 ships.

Comment: Yesterday I clicked on my gulp or grunt file and the task runner was there. Today I do the same and it's not there. Any ideas how to make it appear again. I understand this is a pre-release but I have set up a lot of gulp tasks now and I can't use them. I would imagine many others will be confused by the task runner appearing and then going away again.

Comment: Update - I just closed and then opened the project again and the task runner appears now when I right click on the gulpfile.

Comment: Just a note - doesn't look like this got fixed with CTP5.

Comment: @MadsKvistKristensen Is there a gulp template? or do you need to generate one yourself?

Comment: @Tim, there isn't one. I created it, but it didn't make it into CTP 6 as planned. It'll be in the next release.

Comment: Mads - does anything have to be done special to get gulp files to load in CTP6? My file loads ok in Preview but not in CTP6.

Comment: @ShawnHubbard CTP 6 should be even better with Gulp than Preview was. Does it work in the command line? If there is a version mismatch try going to `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> External Web Tools` and move the PATH line item up to the top

Comment: Sorry Mads, it does help to remember to pull down Gulp locally when setting up a new machine. Looks like we are good now, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem with VS2015 - TRX was showing "no tasks found" even though I had a valid, linted, gulpfile.js in the site root. I found the answer here: http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=4258

Steps: Close VS. Open a cmd prompt from the site root and run `npm install`. Re-open VS and you should see your tasks in TRX. It worked for me.

EDIT: I had gulp installed globally but still encountered this "error." The above steps resolved the issue though.

Answer (score 1):

Barryman9000's answer helped me on the right track. I started with an empty ASP.NET 5 project in VS2015 and had no package.json file at the project root. Running `npm install` gave me an error message about missing package.json. After adding that file with the default dependencies from another ASP.NET 5 project, the Dependencies started downloading and my gulpfile tasks appeared in the Task Runner Explorer.

Answer (score -2):

In your bash, go to the directory gulpfile.js is installed in and run:

```
npm install gulp
```

Why the downvotes?  Please read the OP's question and the comments beneath it.  Also, note that the answer with, currently, the most points has nothing to do with the question.  Also please note that Mads Kristensen himself said that the issue was to install gulp.

Also, as for the commenter "Bonner" of this answer, note that Bash doesn't mean Linux.  You can install git bash for Windows and run all of your NPM and Git commands there.  Most developers I know use that bash on windows for all npm needs.

Lastly, if your Gulp Task Runner is not working, that is most likely because it is not recognizing your gulpfile.  That is due to gulp not being installed.  VS2015 didn't always install gulp for you.  So the fix was to install gulp globally (As Mads Kristensen said), or directly where your gulpfile is.  Also, restarting or re-installing VS sometimes kickstarted the gulp installation if you're lucky.

Conclusion: My answer is the correct answer.  I reference the actual OP Question, comments beneath it, Mads Kristensen, and even the accepted answer.  Yet, this answer is in the negative and some random answer about how to use the "View" menu in Visual Studio has 40 points.

Comment: @Bonner O.o, who said anything about linux command line?  I haven't used Linux myself in like 10 years.  You're weird.

Comment: "In  your bash" bash being the bourne again shell, which only runs in *nix, or an emulated *nix environment.

Comment: @Bonner Oh, okay.  You didn't realize Bash is a common term, and a tool frequently used in NPM configurations including configuring gulp.  I see where you messed up.